# Where can I find cash & ST Equivalents on financial statements

Tags: accounting

I'm trying to calculate the excess cash from financial statements using the following formula:

Excess Cash=MAX(Cash & ST Equivalents−20% * Net Sales or Revenues,0)

I'm having trouble finding the cash & ST Equivalents on financial statements. From what I have googled, I keep getting cash & cash equivalents instead. I'm wondering if these two are the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are the same. That bucket essentially accounts for highly liquid investments (money markets, etc.) that can be converted to cash very quickly, as well as "cash" itself.